# What sort of things can be done with PostGIS that can't be done using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, gis, geospatial, spatial, postgis

I'm about to start a GIS project, and I want to know if I really need PostGIS or if MySQL's Spatial Extensions are sufficient?

Comment: Be more specific - way too vague

Comment: If you don't tell us what you want to do, we can't possibly answer about which database is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS is a complete spatialdb and has been for a while. MySQL continues to only implement the Minimum Bounding Rectangle functions
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html

If you want to do spatial work on FOSS DB your only real choices at this point are
1) PostGIS
2) Spatialite

There are community editions of the other DBs that have spatial extensions as well that you can use.